# How to import one module to another in Django/Python?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, module

I'm just getting started with Python and Django. So within my Django application, I created a new module and within that, I want to import some variable defined in the parent module. However, I am getting certain errors while I tried various combinations.
Below is how my directory structure looks like

[image]

Now in my `kafka_producer.py` I am trying to import `constants.py`.

`kafka_producer.py`:

```
from confluent_kafka import Producer
import sys
import logging
import json
from my_app.constants import KAFKA_BROKER_URL

logging.basicConfig()

#Assign Configuration
conf = {'bootstrap.servers': KAFKA_BROKER_URL}
print(conf)
```

However, I am getting `no module found error`. What is the correct way of importing modules in Python?

Comment: your attempt to import `constants.py` is fine. `from confluent_kafka import Producer` is causing your import error. Where is 'confluent_kafka' located?

Answer (score 0):

It should work if you write:

```
from ..constants import KAFKA_BROKER_URL
```

Through this way, you leave the `kafka` directory and you are in your `my_app` directory.

Comment: I get this error :
ValueError: attempted relative import beyond top-level package

Answer (score 0):

Can you please paste full trace of error, as in :
*ModuleNotFoundError: No module named --name*

I want to know what it is saying in --name.

One thing you can try is adding path of your app to the environment variable PATH.

Try adding below lines in your kafka_producer.py

```
import sys
import os
sys.path.append(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath('__file__'))))
```